# Disable VMware BIOS Legacy Diskette

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, vmware-esx, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

In the main tab of VMware BIOS setup utility there is an option to disable "Legacy Diskette A" (and B).

Which is the option to get this by means of the `vmx` configuration files?

I tried:

```
floppy0.present = "FALSE" 
floppy1.present = "FALSE"
```

but (without using the BIOS setup utility) Arch Linux guest OS still sees `fd0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to [disable the Floppy Disk Controller in the VM's BIOS](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2045015).

Anyway, why do you edit your VMs by hand? Don't do this. [A kitten is harmed every time you edit a VMX file by hand](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/03/a-kitten-is-also-harmed-every-time-you-edit-a-vmx-file-by-hand.html).

edit:
I created a VM (ESXi 5.5 / HW 10) without a floppy device. However, Arch still shows /dev/fd0. The only way I found to get rid of it was disabling the floppy controller in the BIOS.

Comment: For my tests I need to run the same VM with different configurations. Changong the configuration with point and click is way too long and error prone. Therefore I wrote a number of Perl scripts to automate the tests. I can change many BIOS settings via my vmx-scripts (including the boot order).

Comment: Well, in that case the kittens probably aren't too seriously hurt :) I wasn't able to have a closer look at this issue but maybe I'll find time tomorrow. What version of Arch are you using?

Comment: Current: 2014.07.03

Comment: There are two places in the BIOS that you need to edit.  The first is "Legacy Diskette A:" on the Main tab.  The second is "Floppy Disk Controller" in the I/O Device Configuration section of the Advanced tab.  Disabled both of those, and the floppy disk should no longer appear in the OS.